# Oracle backup notification via Email

Tags: oracle, email, scheduled-tasks, batch-processing, database-backups

I'm using Oracle 12c and backup by running [exp] command everyday
But my client want me to send Backup result via Email everyday

I've tried to use Windows task schedule for sending email but how can I get the parameter from backup result to put in Email body?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your export log to the mail on your [scheduled task](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-task-to-send-email-in-windows-task.html) 
Also, on Oracle 12c you should use expdp instead of exp.But that's not really a backup. Backups on Oracle are usually done with [RMAN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30545/difference-between-database-dump-export-and-database-backup)